# Why opening apps in Ubuntu Touch takes so long?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Why in current ubuntu touch images, the apps take so long to open? When I click on some app, the phone show the icon of the app selected and the "icon of loading". This is a bug, or is this how it works?

Thanks!

Comment: I would imagine this is a bug, and Canonical will fix it in future, more stable, releases.

Comment: How long is “so long”, in seconds?

Answer (score 2):

When an application is loaded there's a sequence of processes which get loaded before and during the application startup. Ideally we'd like to have applications start from a partially started state (as happens on Android) which would be faster. Unfortunately at the moment we can't do that due to limitations in upstart & apparmor, but we hope to in the near future.